# Error establishing connection with local DB and google cloud SQL using data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion

Need to create a pipeline to export data from local PostgreSQL DB to Google Cloud SQL using Google Cloud DataFusion. Using wrangler to first test the connections with local DB and CloudSQL.

1. While trying to establish a connection with local DB, I am getting connection failed exception. Hostname, port, username and password are correct.
2. For establishing connection with Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL), I used this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880595/cant-connect-cloud-data-fusion-with-google-cloud-sql-for-postgresql) to build the JAR but got SocketFactory instantiation error.

Steps followed for both:

1. In Wrangler UI, click add connection
2. Click databases
3. Then add the respective jar (JDBC driver)
4. Add connection details

Kindly help with how to resolve these issues.

Comment: Please provide the error along with the stack trace - it's hard to determine the cause of an error without more context.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the full stacktrace for the exception you saw? If it did not show the exception from UI, you can go to "SYSTEM ADMIN" link at the top right hand corner and click on "View Logs" for Wrangler Service.

Comment: Please provide feedback in the comment section "add comment" instead of using "Your Answer" - thank you